# How to align spans within a table cell with the spans in the cell below it?

Tags: html, css

I've a requirement in which I want to show an icon, a text and another icon inside a table cell. To create this, I'm building spans within a td. Something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>ICON 1</span>
      <span>Some Value</span>
      <span>ICON 2</span>
    <td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>ICON 3</span>
      <span>Some big big value</span>
      <span>ICON 4</span>
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem with this approach is the spans are not getting properly aligned. Icons will be of same size always, but the middle span (text) will vary in length. For e.g. the above code will appear as:
[image]

But, what I want is something like:

[image]

Both the icons and the text has to be a part of a single cell. Creating different columns for text and icons will break something else for me.

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

**Update:**
How can I get the text to be right-aligned?

[image]

Comment: please post your css

Comment: You have to enclose the spans in td

Comment: Sorry, I just missed <td> in the post. I have it my actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `td` is missing.

you could look at `float`.*(assuming icons are same size)*

```css
td span {
  float:left;
  margin:0.25em;
}
td span:last-of-type {
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>ICON 1</span>
      <span>Some Value</span>
      <span>ICON 2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>ICON 3</span>
      <span>Some big big value</span>
      <span>ICON 4</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

align right on middle span N

```css
tr {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  }
td {
  display:table-row;
  }
td span {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:0.25em;
}
td span:nth-child(2) {
  text-align:right;
  width:100%;
  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>ICON 1</span>
      <span>Some Value</span>
      <span>ICON 2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>ICON 3</span>
      <span>Some big big value</span>
      <span>ICON 4</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Just one more thing, how can I make the text right align within that span.

Comment: @akash wich span do you talk about ? because none of them has a width given, just a margin :)

Comment: I'm referring to the middle span. (see the update section of the post).
Only the width of the icons will be known initially, the width of the text can vary and hence we cannot assign a starting width to the middle span.

Comment: then each span should be turned into td ( see snippet 2 in answer ... i do not recommend this) or the second move to  last position & not floating with text-align right on TD

Comment: I believe you meant something like [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/0x5esv9L/4/). This is working fine, just having some vertical alignment issues.

Comment: @akash all 3 spans need the same margin value ;) https://jsfiddle.net/0x5esv9L/5/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. Found exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

span {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <span>ICON 1</span>
    <span>Some Value</span>
    <span>ICON 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>ICON 1</span>
    <span>Some Value lorem ipsum</span>
    <span>ICON 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the *[td](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td)* tag.

This set columns in your table, no CSS needed.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnynfv9t/

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ICON 1</td>
    <td>Some Value</td>
    <td>ICON 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ICON 3</td>
    <td>Some big big value</td>
    <td>ICON 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you forgot to wrap your spans in table columns.

In any case, in your CSS set your spans to display: block. Give then all the same width, pixels or percentages. Add a background image for one icon and set it to top left. Add the other icon as a background image to top right and put padding on the left of the span to sit the text to the right of the icon.